# HI there, I have an ms access report. I want to write vba code to give a different color to only the first three records

Tags: ms-access, report, vba7

I have an ms access report displaying multiple records.
I want to display the first three records in a different background color, I want to write vba-code to accomplish this. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?
Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

I tried coding in detail-events, but then the whole section was displayed in another color.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

This works in print preview:

```
SUB DETAIL_FORMAT
    IF (condition) THEN
        DETAIL.BACKCOLOR = ...
    ELSE
        DETAIL.BACKCOLOR = ...
    END IF
END SUB
```

This works in report view:

```
SUB DETAIL_PAINT
    IF (condition) THEN
        DETAIL.BACKCOLOR = ...
    ELSE
        DETAIL.BACKCOLOR = ...
    END IF
END SUB
```

Comment: Hi there, indeed, this works. It took me a while to find out why the format event did not do anything, now I realized it should be the paint event. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Should work in Detail section Format, Print, or Paint.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Place a textbox named tbxCnt in Detail section with ControlSource of =1 and RunningSum set to OverAll (can be set not visible). Code options:

1. Conditional Formatting rule on each textbox `Expression is: [tbxCnt]<4`
2. VBA can test for value of tbxCnt to set Detail section backcolor with:
   `If Me.tbxCnt < 4 Then Me.Detail.Backcolor = vbYellow Else: Me.Detail.Backcolor = vbWhite`
   or
   `Me.Detail.Backcolor = IIf(Me.tbxCnt < 4, vbYellow, vbWhite)`

Make sure AlternateBackColor is set for NoColor.

Comment: Hi there, this works great, thanks!

Comment: If an answer resolves issue, please mark accepted.